# jQuery postcode validation space required

Tags: jquery, regex

The following line of code works well to check a postcode format. However it doesn't allow to use space in between:

```
var postMatch = /[A-z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}/i;
```

This would be correct: se34tyu

This one no: se34 tyu

What can I add to make that happen?

[Full code](http://jsfiddle.net/8qUtd/)

Comment: the "tyu" part is not correct anyway, the last three are a digit and two characters, not three characters.

Comment: ok that was just an example, however I have been trying with this one se14 3uf (UK postcode)

Comment: Also, you're missing one format: AA9A 9AA, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom for all postcodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\s*` for allowing an optional space.

```
/[A-z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}\s*[0-9][A-Z]{2}/i
```

Comment: @Alex: if I add the `\s*` in your jsfiddle, it works fine when you include a space. Don't forget to "run" the fiddle again if you want to test it there.